# write to .txt and keep writing instead of replace

Tags: android

how do i getting it to make a new line and keep writing instead of replacing my text in the .txt and add a few other stuffs

1.5(this should only be added once in the top i am not sure how to do that)

LAGERIND(text)

KW89668(Cardnumberbox)

RHAL4 (shelfnumberbox)

thats how it should look like in the .txt
[image]

```
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
                 File dir = new File(path);
                dir.mkdirs();
                File file = new File (path + "/append.txt");
String [] saveText = String.valueOf("LAGERIND"+cardnumberbox.getText()+shelfnumberbox.getText()).split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

                cardnumberbox.setText("");

                Save (file ,saveText);

   public static void Save(File file, String[] data)
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try
        {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        try
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
                {
                    fos.write(data[i].getBytes());
                    if (i < data.length-1)
                    {
                        fos.write("\n".getBytes());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                fos.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
```

Comment: and what did you get instead?

Comment: If you use the FileWriter object, its constructor takes a boolean value which, if set to true, forces FileWriter to append to the file rather than overwrite its contents.

Comment: i got it to work with keep writing and make new lines but i am still not sure how to do the 1.5 at the top once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try
    {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Using this constructor appends to the file **FileOutputStream(file, true)**

More details [here (FileOutputStream api doc)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)